# Remove selected rows from multi-column listView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview with two columns and I'm using a context menu to allow users to remove selected rows. To remove the selected rows, I've tried with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
}
```

I suspect this is because the listview has two columns, but I can't figure out a solution to remove selected rows. Removing all rows works with: `listView1.Items.Clear();`.

Comment: Can you edit the first post instead of replying 2 times. If someone gets upvoted  you don't see your posts anymore. or vice versa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest example of BeefTurkey looks correct, but he should decrement the variable `i` after removing a selected item:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++ )
{
    if (listView1.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].Remove();
        i--;
    }
}
```

The index of items larger as `i` is decremented by 1 after the removal. So you should reposition `i` to match the next not tested item.

Comment: This solution works simply like a charm, hasn't broken on me so far! +1

Answer (score 2):

```
while (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach(ListViewItem lvItem in lvDocument.SelectedItems)
 {
      lvDocument.Items.Remove(lvItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++ )
    {

        if (listView1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Clear();
        }

    }
```

Is there any way to remove items and re-order the listView so that there are no empty rows in the middle of other rows?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a better solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++ )
{
    if (listView1.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].Remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

```
foreach (ListViewItem Item in LstvClients.Items)
{    
     if (item.Selected)
     {
         LstvClients.Items.Remove(Item);
     }
}
```

(Yours is better, item.Remove())

Comment: Actually, this won't move. You can't mess with a collection while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using something slightly different then the others to remove all the selected items from a ListView control:

```
foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(listViewItem);
}
```

I'm not sure how this would match up performance-wise to the other posted methods on large lists, but I think it is a little cleaner looking in cases where that isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to remove all selected items. The method is to always access fist selected item with an index 0 and loop until no more selected items left. You cannot refer to other items inside collection with an absolute index safely since indexes will change as soon as you delete one of the items.

```
while( listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(lvFiles.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
do
{ 
  this.listView1.CheckedItems[0].Remove(); 
} while (this.listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0);
```

This works better